# Can I use variable value in email body when using UTL_mail package in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

Context:
I'm comparing 2 variables and generating an email with variable values in the body of the email

------------Code-----------------------------

```
--Variable 1
select sum(sales) 
into V1_sales
from sales

--variable 2
selsct sum(sales)
into v2_sales
from yesretday_sales

if v2_sales > V1_sales
then 
EMAIL_ALERT
(p_mail_host => 'mailhost.abc.com',
p_from => 'sender.abc.com',
p_to => 'rec.abc.com',
p_subject => 'Sales of yesterday is greater than today'
p_message => 'Message: Today's sales which is'@v1_sales 'is lesser than yesretday's sales which is @v2_sales'
endif 


Explanation:
Trying to compare 2 variables and include the variable in the email body, I'm using UTL_MAIL in orcale SQL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

I suggest you create a variable which will be used to compose message text, and use it when calling the procedure.

Also, if you declare the third variable (v3_sales), it can be used in the message as well.

Something like this:

```
declare
  v_message varchar2(500);
  v1_sales  number;
  v2_sales  number;
  v3_sales  number;
begin
  ...
  v3_sales := v1_sales - v2_sales;

  v_message := 'Message: Today''s sales which is '           || v1_sales ||
               'is lesser than yesterday''s sales which is ' || v2_sales ||
               '. Difference is ' || v3_sales;

  email_alert (...,
               p_message => v_message
              );
end;
```

Code you wrote is *wrong* because of invalid single quote usage; you have to use two consecutive quotes if it is used within the string.

Comment: Yes got it and I'm not aware of use of pipes for variables. Also can I store the difference between 2 variables i.e. v1_sales - v2_sales as new variable say V3_Sales?

Comment: Double pipe is *concatenation operator*; it concatenates strings, but - as you can see - variables can be also used. As of the 3rd variable: sure, no problem. Declare v3_sales and put the result into it. I've edited my answer; have a look, please.

Comment: Wow it worked thanks. Sorry one more clarification, if I have do it in new line like Yesday's sales : 12000 in one line, today's sales :10000 in one line and difference : 2000 in one line how to do it in new line?

Comment: Concatenate `chr(10)` where you want to break a line, e.g. `|| v1_sales || chr(10) || ...`

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't get the concatenate piece which you were saying. Tried it out but still it's coming in the same sentence